# AutoCAD Get Length from BlockReference.

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

**The Problem**

im struggling to get the Length from a BlockReference in AutoCAD.
I somehow being a math noob got the Widh & Height but i cannot get the Length 
so far of a BlockReference. 
Is there a way of getting the Length of a BlockReference. Ive looked through the AutoCad API but without succsess. Maybe someone can show me the Direction.

**What ive Done**

```
   public static double GetBlockWidthAndHeight(BlockReference blockReference) {
            try {
                var db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
                var blockname = blockReference.Name;
                double width = 0;

                using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {
                    var bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
                    if (!bt.Has(blockname)) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    var btrec = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[blockname], OpenMode.ForRead, false);
                    Extents3d? bounds;
                    bounds = btrec.Bounds;
                    if (bounds.HasValue) {
                        var ext = bounds.Value;
                        width = ext.MaxPoint.X - ext.MinPoint.X;
                        double height = ext.MaxPoint.Y - ext.MinPoint.Y;
                    }
                    else {
                        var bref = new BlockReference(Point3d.Origin, bt[blockname]);
                        bounds = bref.Bounds;
                        var ext = bounds.Value;
                        width = ext.MaxPoint.X - ext.MinPoint.X;
                        double height = ext.MaxPoint.Y - ext.MinPoint.Y;
                        bref.Dispose();
                    }
                    tr.Commit();
                }

                return width;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your block reference a 3D object?  If so. I noticed that you currently get the bounds of the object along the X axis (Width) and Y Axis (Height) but you're missing utilizing the Z Axis.  If the Block Reference is a 2D object, then going about the method you described won't work since that information simply isn't there.

You can also try looking at the properties of the Block Reference under the AutoCAD 'Properties' palette. Depending on how the block reference was made, there may already be values for it's dimensions that you can simply access via the API.

Here's a link to Kean Wamsley's blog giving some brief examples of how to utilize the API to access the block info directly - http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/03/accessing-the-properties-of-a-dynamic-autocad-block-using-net.html

Comment: thanks for your time. i have a 2d drawing. Thanks for the link is there a way to get the length with the same method?-

Comment: Again, being a 2D object, you won't be able to use the bounds of the object to get anything outside of the bounds of the X and Y axis as that information simply does not exist.  

Your best bet will be if there is a "Length" value of some kind defined in the Properties of the Block Reference. This is completely dependent, however; on how the block reference was made and whether or not the creator put that value there.